# I can't get my device supported by Google Play Services to get my Snapchat to work

Tags: google-account, google-play-services, snapchat

I recently updated my phone, before updating Snapchat was working fine but now it logged me out and I can't log back in as it says " Google Play Services which most applications rely on, is not supported by your device. Please contact your manufacturer for assistance."

I have downloaded Google Play Services onto my phone but it says it need to be updated otherwise it will not work. When I go to Google Play Services it says "Authentication is required.You need to sign in to your Google Account", which under Settings → Accounts I am signed in. But I cant access the app.

Comment: Have you login to the Play Store?

Comment: Yep, but It says authentication is required

Answer (score 0):

This may be an authentication issue with your account and connecting to the Google Play servers. Go ahead and try removing your account from the device, and re-adding it. Make sure you remember the password!